# How to control the animation to be played by a specific times in unity animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I have an animator where there is a state with an animation which is set to be looped. I want to control it to play 3 times or once. How to do it?

```
public override void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        int normalizedTime = Convert.ToInt32((stateInfo.normalizedTime));
        if (normalizedTime == animator.GetInteger(PlayTimes))
        {
            animator.SetBool("ToNextState", true);
        }  
    }
```

I try to do it by this way, but I think it's not perfect because sometimes this animation can not be stopped accurately.

Is there an event triggered when the animation comes to end?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a count inside of your gameObject? Setup an `int` and provide it the number of times the animation can loop `3` then at the start of animation in code set the `animationRan` variable to 0. Now in your animation window place a function at the end of the animation which is called which increases your `animationRan` variable.

Then at the start of the animation make a method call to check if the `animationRan` has hit the limit and if so do something

Something like this

```
...
public int animationLimit = 3;
public int animationRan = 0;
....

public void OnAnimationStart()
{
    animationRan = 0;
}

public void OnAnimationEnd()
{
    if(animationRan < animationLimit)
    {
        Animation.Stop();
    }
}
```